# MYSQL avergae and MAX number

Tags: mysql

I need to query a database table.  structure:
    id---bid ---veh_id---user_id

There is many data, all are veh_id related.  User can place bid on veh_id as many as they want and on many veih_id.

I need to find the average bid on each veh_id and also the max bid receive for that veh_id.  Can this be done in one SQL query. The optimal would have the difference betwenn the average and the max number.  All group by veh_id.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start with a sqlfiddle.

Comment: You could start by learning SQL

Comment: @Bojangles Unnecessarily rude, dontcha think?

Comment: Not at all. More just realistic

Comment: @Bojangles Regardless, I find it nice when people give other people the benefit of the doubt. There's a way to be realistic and helpful at the same time.

Comment: And getting defensive about me telling someone to learn SQL the proper way instead of saying "I need this" is not it

Comment: @Bojangles I see what you did there.  This could get recursive very quickly. `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
SELECT MAX(bid), AVG(bid) FROM someTable GROUP BY veh_id
```

Comment: So simple.  I thaught I could not use many  MAX'S and AVG's toghether.

Comment: @maphaneuf: why would you think that?

Comment: I did a request once and ask to count multiple things on the same request.  I kept getting an error and I read on Internet I couln not use count on multiple fields in the same query, I thaugt this would apply here too.

Comment: @maphaneuf What you read there is wrong.